# how do I define type of object containing properties only of a particular type

Tags: typescript

I have an object of type

```
var obj : any = {
   "ab" : new X(),
   "cd" : new X(),
   ....
   ....
}
```

basically all the properties in an object are of type `X`, but the properties are being added dynamically.

I am creating this object like below (the prop name is dynamic and not fixed)

```
obj[prop] = new X();
```

How do I define this type in typescript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With an [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types):

```
interface Dict {
    [index: string]: X;
}

let obj: Dict = {};
obj['ab'] = new X();
```